# Can you use JDBC sources via Azure Linked Services using the Azure Integration Runtime on a remote machine?

Tags: azure, jdbc, odbc, azure-data-factory, linked-service

All,

We are in the process of migrating our clients to ADF using Integration Runtimes. The clients have the Azure Integration Runtime installed on an on-premise server and we are needing to pull data from a remote database through that connection.  The "legacy" product allowed for JDBC connections so we have JDBC drivers installed for the proprietary databases (Progress DataDirect, Pervasive, etc.) but there isn't an option in the Azure Linked Services option for JDBC.  We can use ODBC, but that would require purchasing and installing an ODBC driver on each of the client machines.  We'd like to use JDBC, but can't find anything that would allow us to do it.  Has anyone else run into this and are there any work arounds?

We would prefer to not have each of the clients that used JDBC purchase and install ODBC drivers.  We also aren't interested in developing our own ODBC driver that wraps the JDBC driver.  We are specifically looking for a way to use the existing JDBC drivers that are installed on the client systems to pull data from their database to create an Azure Dataset.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no JDBC linked service available in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

The Progress DataDirect/Pervasive etc can spit the data in the txt/csv file locally and since you plan to install slef hosted runtime ADF can read the text file and write that any supported sink .